# Solr sharding for complex query performance optimization

Tags: solr, sharding, lucene, solrcloud

I have relatively small index about 1 mln documents for high load site. I'm running relatively complex function queries against it and performance is not acceptable. So I'm hesitation about moving current master+slaves topology to SolrCloud with at least 3 shards and n replicas so all function queries will be distributed across shards and response time should be at least 3 times smaller plus small footprint on merging result sets(Is it true?). 
So my question is it worth sharding(and adding complexity) to solve performance problems not index size problems(most common reason to shard your index).

Comment: 1) Have you tried profiling via debugQuery=true ? 2) Have you looked into cache usage and tweaked you cache parameters to avoid evictions?

Comment: If performance is the issue, you can use Load balancer to distribute your search queries to multiple solr nodes